# How windows store app gets the client certificate issuer form server

Tags: ssl, certificate, httpclient

I am writing a windows store app with `Windows::Web::Http` namespace, and I am trying to find a way to get the list of accepted client certificate issuer from server if server requires client certificate.
Same as `WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_ISSUER_LIST` when you call `WinHttpQueryOption()`, which is not supported in store app...

Comment: As I know, there is no way to get server acceptable client certificate list in client side through Windows::Http namespace, and the way I use is to use openssl to handle the client cert callback with calling SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_cb().

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no way to get server acceptable client certificate list in client side through Windows::Http namespace, and the way I use is to use openssl to handle the client cert callback with calling SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_cb().